# How to export string created by pam_set_data()

Tags: unix, environment-variables, pam

(my C is a bit rusty)

I want to pass some data from outside the authentication process into the resulting shell (or possibly other service). It occurs to me that I could embed the data into the submitted username, then, at the top of the pam stack seperate the username and data, update the username (with pam_set_item()) and preserve the data (e.g. with pam_set_data()) but how do I then present the data to the service being authenticated?

If I just setenv(*varname, *data, 1) will this suffice to make it appear in the child process environment?

If I use pam_set_data() does this create an identifier I can use in pam_env?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use pam_set_data() but to get it in your program, you have to use pam_get_data(). If you want your data to be available in the environment, take a look at the pam_env.so module.

Comment: Surely I can only read using pam_get_data() in the same process I called pam_set_data() in? And I only saw mention of a fixed, predefined set of names for variables in the documentation for pam_env

Comment: Yes you have to be in the same process to be able to use pam_get_data(). pam_env allows you to put whatever environment variables you want in a file and load for the process.